# Deploy shinydashboard referencing to a local file

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I had dashboard that works great locally. The problem when I want to deploy it is that all my data sources are in my C drive.

I am not sure how to refer to a local file. I have seen many code examples and all refer to a sever somewhere.

Is it possible to referrer to a local file ?

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
require(htmltools)

indicators <- read.csv ("C:/Users/user1/Desktop/idicators.csv")
```

thanks

Comment: where do you put the indicators <- read.csv ("C:/Users/user1/Desktop/idicators.csv")? you should put that in your server.R above the shinyServer(function(input, output) {})

Comment: Thanks that worked but now it have a problem trying to load multiple files

indicators <- read.csv ("C:/Users/user1/Desktop/idicators.csv") 

trend <- read.csv ("C:/Users/user1/Desktop/trend.csv") 


is won't load

I try separating the two files with ; like so

indicators <- read.csv ("C:/Users/user1/Desktop/idicators.csv"); 

trend <- read.csv ("C:/Users/user1/Desktop/trend.csv") 

but still won't load

Comment: Put the files in the same directory as the server.R, the call it in normal way indicators <- read.csv("idicators.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors =FALSE);trend <- read.csv("trend.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can refer a local file easily by storing in R with a particular 
   dataframe name.
2. Then you can use that dataframe name in any of your
       R    script  as a variable name and then it will work fine.